# jQuery fadeIn fadeOut - IE8 does not fade

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

Can anyone tell me why a .jpg would not fade in or fade out in IE8.  Right now it is just disapearing and reappearing with no opacity changes.  I have this set up locally and on a publishing server, strange thing is the images fade in and out just fine locally, it's only when I go to the publishing server that they cease to fade.

Just wondering if I am missing something someone could quickly help me with off the top of their heads.

Here is the gcRotateContent that is on the publishing server, If I just throw an image up and do a fade in out it works, for some reason it doesn't work with this markup.

```
<div class="gcRotateContent">
   <div id="USCFRR2EN" class="gcEmployeeProfile">
      <div class="gcEmployeeProfileHeading">
         Meet John</div>
      <div class="gcEmployeeProfileContent">
         <div class="gcEmployeeProfileHRPad">
         </div>
         <div class="gcEmployeeProfileHR">
         </div>
         <div class="gcEmployeeProfileHRPad">
         </div>
         <div class="gcEmployeeProfileSLVideo">
            <img src="/PublishingImages/Profile_JOHN-190x96.jpg" alt="Portrait of employee John."
               height="96" width="190"></div>
         <div class="gcEmployeeProfileName">
         </div>
         <div class="gcEmployeeProfileTitle">
            Software Development Lead, Server Performance</div>
         <div class="gcEmployeeProfileQuote">
            “You will find no other company with the sheer breadth of technologies. The things you get to see and learn from other
            people are amazing.”</div>
      </div>
      <div class="gcEmployeeProfileFooter">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="gcRotate">
      <div class="gcRotateContent">
         <div style="border: solid 2px black; text-align: center; width: 150px;">
            This is first content
            <img src="http://pix.motivatedphotos.com/2008/6/16/633492359109161542-Skills.jpg"
               alt="First" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gcRotateContent">
         <div style="border: solid 2px black; text-align: center; width: 150px">
            This is second content
            <img src="http://www.funnycorner.net/funny-pictures/5010/cheezburger-locats.jpg"
               alt="Second" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gcRotateContent">
         <div style="border: solid 2px black; text-align: center; width: 150px">
            This is third content
            <img src="http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2007/06/business.jpg" alt="Third" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>



   <div>
      This shouldn't move.
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      function fadeContent() {

         $(".gcRotateContent").first().customFadeOut(500, function() {
            $(".gcRotateContent:hidden:first").customFadeIn(500)
         });
         $(".gcRotateContent").first().appendTo($(".gcRotateContent").parent());
      }

      $(".gcRotate").height(0);

      $(".gcRotateContent").each(
         function() {
            if ($(".gcRotate").height() < $(this).height()) {
               $(".gcRotate").height($(this).height());
            }
         }
         );

      $(".gcRotateContent").each(function() {
         $(this).css("display", "none")
      });

      $(".gcRotate").hover(function() { window.clearInterval(timer) }, function() { timer = window.setInterval("fadeContent()", 2000) });

      $(".gcRotateContent").first().show(0);
      var timer = window.setInterval("fadeContent()", 2000);

      (function($) {
         $.fn.customFadeIn = function(speed, callback) {
            $(this).fadeIn(speed, function() {
               if (jQuery.browser.msie)
                  $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
               if (callback != undefined)
                  callback();
            });
         };
         $.fn.customFadeOut = function(speed, callback) {
            $(this).fadeOut(speed, function() {
               if (jQuery.browser.msie)
                  $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
               if (callback != undefined)
                  callback();
            });
         };
      })(jQuery);
   </script>
```

Comment: Let us see your markup and script.

Comment: Show us an example and I guarantee someone can help.

Comment: @Eric - As far as MSIE goes, IE8 isn't actually THAT bad!

Comment: Fair point. It certainly beats IE6.

Comment: @theDawckta - Again, this works fine for me. Can we have a link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, css setting position:relative on the image, aparently ie8 doesn't like that, is there a workaround I wonder, the search begins.

Answer (score 58):

Apparently there's a workaround!

Simply set the absolute/relative positioned elements the following css attributes:

```
opacity:inherit;
filter:inherit;
```

E.g:

```
<div>
<img id='myImg' src='http://mydomain.com' style='position:absolute;top:10px;left:5px;filter:inherit;opacity:inherit' />
</div>
```

Have fun,

Omer

Comment: This works like a charm! 
  I had the same issue on my site. I was fading div elems that contained images. 
  To fix this for IE9 and IE7 it was enough to set appropriate dimensions to the div elems. Before that divs had 0,0 dimensions since images inside them were absolute positioned.
  But after that still IE8 didn't want to fade, it just poped up. Setting opacity and filter to inherit, for all elements inside divs, fixed that.

Comment: .ie8 * { opacity: inherit; filter: inherit; }

Comment: This is a good general workaround for opacity and fade in/out.  The small caveat is that filters tend to be used in other workarounds (text-shadows, box-shadow support) in IE. This complicates those solutions if they are within a block that should dynamically fade in/out.

Comment: * { opacity: inherit; filter: inherit; } worked for me.
I also had to add #mydiv {background: white} for the hover effect to be properly considered.

Comment: fantastic! this is an easy solution to an annoying problem

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem, and all the css ticks didn't worked.
The fadeIn/Out worked on FF and Chrome, but not in IE8, the element didn't showed up at all.
In IE7 they just went from invisible to visible.

So to fix my problem I just wanted to keep the fadeIn/Out on the other browsers and make the elements appear in IE8. The solution was to use the callback like so:

```
$(".elements").fadeIn("slow",function(){$(this).show()}):
$(".elements").fadeOut("slow",function(){$(this).hide()}):
```

This way I always force the result I want in the end.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty fix (or if the suggestions above are just not working, as is my case) you can simply replace jQuery's fadeIn/fadeOut with show/hide. So in the html do:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript src="ieFixes.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

and in some javascript file of IE hacks (eg ieFixes.js) put:

```
jQuery.fn.fadeIn = function() {
    this.show();
}

jQuery.fn.fadeOut = function() {
    this.hide();
}
```

You'll have to tweak this a bit if you're chaining animate calls, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your image with a div (of the same size) with a background image and fade-in/-out the div.

```
<div style="background-image:url('paper.gif');height:xxxpx;width:xxxpx"></div>
```

Comment: I have a feeling it's a problem with @theDawckta's code rather than MSIE itself. 

Try the following in IE8 and see if it fades in and out... http://www.eideus.com/demoImageFade.html

Comment: I cannot change any of the elements inside gcRotateContent.

Comment: gcRotateContent......? Okay, now it's time to edit your question and add some code!

Comment: @Sam I put your banana code on my server and it works fine.  Really perplexing.