# jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut not compatible with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have written this script to fade in/out an error container. it works fine in FF and Chrome but does not work at all in IE8.

You can play with the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mostafatalebi/8tw2x/

or look the below code:

Here is the Container CSS:

```
.error-box
{
    filter:inherit; 
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webki-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #C00;
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    opacity:inherit;
    filter:inherit;
}
```

Here is the HTML DOM:

```
<label class="form-label">Email</label><br />
                <div class="form-field-holder">
                    <input id='email' type="text" name="email" class="form-input" />
                    <div class="error-box"><!-- jQuery --></div><br /> 
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery code to handle the process:

```
        $(document).ready(function(e) {

            var email = $("#email");
            email.on('blur', function(){
                console.log(email_regexp.test(email.val()));
                if(!email_regexp.test(email.val()))
                {
                    $(this).siblings('.error-box').fadeIn(600).text("رایانامه شما اشتباه است");                                                         
                }   
                else
                {
                    $(this).siblings('.error-box').fadeOut(600);    
                }
            });                                                                                                                                                             
        });
```

Comment: jQuery + not compatible = jQuery 2.x; go back to 1.x for older browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### On compatability and jQuery

jQuery 2.x is only meant to be used with Internet Explorer 9 and up. If you wish to have support for fading elements in Internet Explorer 8 (and down to 6), you will need to use jQuery 1.x instead, which still supported the older IE filter property.

I have confirmed that switching to jQuery 1.x resolves the issue. Nothing else was necessary, even though it seems in the past additional workarounds may have been needed.

#### On console and old Internet Explorer

One other thing to keep in mind is that by `console` doesn't initially exist in IE8. As such, any attempt to call `console.log` will cause problems. If you wish to use it, pre-check for the availability of `console` first. You could do this with `&&`, though this is [considered an *abusage*](http://sampsonblog.com/260/abusages-in-javascript):

```
window.console && console.log( email_regexp.test( email.val() ) );
```

Alternatively, you can take the more verbose route and make it a proper condition:

```
if ( window.console ) { console.log( email_regexp.test( email.val() ) ); }
```

If you don't want to litter your code with console checks, just define your own:

```
if ( !window.console ) {
    // When debug is true, console.log alerts
    var debug = true;
    window.console = {
        log: function ( message ) {
            if ( debug ) alert( message );
        }
    };
}
```

Further Reading: [jQuery Browser Support](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [jQuery fadeIn fadeOut - IE8 does not fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766735/jquery-fadein-fadeout-ie8-does-not-fade)

Taken from Omeriko:
'Apparently there's a workaround!

Simply set the absolute/relative positioned elements the following css attributes:

```
opacity:inherit;
filter:inherit;
```

E.g:

```
<div>
<img id='myImg' src='http://mydomain.com' style='position:absolute;top:10px;left:5px;filter:inherit;opacity:inherit' />
</div>
```

Have fun,

Omer'

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a manual fadeIn fadeOut function for IE that removes the filter attribute.
Then it will work perfectly.

Good tutorial on how to do it:

http://www.epochdev.com/blog/tutorials/javascript_development/fixing_jquery_fade_in_and_out_functions_for_internet_explorer

Answer (score 0):

FadeIn and FadeOut does not seem to be supported well in IE8. Although it works as expected on other higher versions of IE.